# Cannot load linked modules from npm/yarn link in WSL

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running into a really strange issue when trying to import a local dependency into my project.

I have a project called 'test_project' and another project that will be linked called 'test_module'. I link test module to the global node_modules folder (I've tried npm link and yarn link). Then in test_project I link test_module. I import test_module into the index.js file, but when I do a yarn/npm start I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '/mnt/c/users/<my_username>/Projects/test_module/Users'.
```

For whatever reason '/Users' is getting added to the end of the path and I have no idea why. I've blown away my environment twice now and it keeps happening. Is this an issue with WSL? Do I have something configured wrong?

EDIT: 'test_project' was generated from create-react-app, with no modifications. In case you wanted to know how my environment is setup.

EDIT2: I tried this in Window's CMD, and everything worked properly. So it seems like the issues is caused by a combination of WSL, my node installation, and whatever the hell else :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to resolve the issue. You need to edit your wsl config and set the root to '/'. My theory is somewhere a relative path is being used, and using '/' as the root removes '/mnt/' from the path, allowing it to step back properly. However, I can't back it up with facts :D

Anyway, the fix is easy.

```
sudo vim /etc/wsl.conf
```

Then add this field so the file looks like this:

```
[automount]

root = /
options = "metadata"
```

(I have the options field there to resolve permission issues)

Then fully logout/signout, log back in, unlink the module, blow away the node_modules folder, run npm install, and then re-link. It should all work at that point.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This issue had been driving me nuts for a long time but I was able to solve it for the project I'm working on. (Remounting the WSL root didn't fix the issue for me unfortunately.) The symptoms are *slightly* different from the ones in the original question but I'm hoping what I found might at least provide some insight.

For me, the issue was a combination of factors. It occurred whenever I tried to run `react-scripts start` for a certain project. The odd part was that I had another project in the WSL with a nearly identical setup that ran fine.

After some hacking, I narrowed the issue down to the [case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin) that `react-scripts` was using internally. By dropping a bunch of `console.log()` statements in the [fileExistsWithCase](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L74) method, I was able to pinpoint the cause of the issue.

The method confirms whether a file/directory exists on disk with casing that matches the passed string (`filepath`). In order to do this, it recursively checks each directory in the path. Unfortunately the error logging appears to be a bit broken because, when an error bubbles up through the recursion loops, it appends the name of the folder in error as if it were the original filename (reported this as [an issue in the create-react-app repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8463)).

For example, the error from the original question was

```
Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '/mnt/c/users/<my_username>/Projects/test_module/Users'.
```

In this case, after recursing a few times, the library listed everything in `/mnt/c` and, seeing that the `users` directory did not exist but the `Users` directory did, the error bubbled up and was incorrectly reported with a bad file of `/mnt/c/users/<my_username>/Projects/test_module/Users`.

Now, when checking each file/directory, the library first checks its cache. And ahead of time it [primes the cache with the current working directory](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L129). This was ultimately why one of my projects worked but the other didn't. The project that worked was using npm so the node_modules were of the form `$PWD/node_modules/foo` which would stop recursing once `$PWD` was reached. The other project, however, was using pnpm and the failing dependencies were hoisted up to a higher directory. In my case, those dependencies failed whenever it tried to validate a directory on my system called `/mnt/c/Users/[username]/wslhome`, which it saw as `WSLHome` on disk.

I was lucky enough to just be able to rename `WSLHome` to `wslhome` to get things working for my project. Unfortunately `/mnt/c/Users` wouldn't be as easily renamed since it's created by Windows.

Overall, it looks like the issue largely hinges on how the absolute paths of the package's dependencies are defined and whether the casing matches what Node's `path` sees.

UPDATE: When I went to use the project today it started failing again, this time complaining about the "Users" directory having improper casing. -_- So it appears that the issue may be somewhat inconsistent. I came upon an article about [updating case sensitivity options when using Windows directories](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/) and, after adding `case=dir` to my wsl.conf options and restarting the subsystem, the error disappeared. Given its inconsistent nature, however, I can't say for certain whether that was the solution.

One additional observation that's potentially related is that discrepancies seem to be visible when running `readlink -f` against a dependency directory. Sometimes the results have the proper casing and sometimes they do not. (For example, right now, `readlink -f ~/dev` improperly returns a subdirectory of `/mnt/c/users` whereas `readlink -f .` correctly returns a subdirectory of `/mnt/c/Users` while in the `~/dev` directory.)